# Error inflating class com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

Im getting this error

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at cl.rpro.vendormobile.tm.controller.activity.ActivityTareas.onCreateView(ActivityTareas.java:56)`

while trying to implement an ExpandableLayout inside a Tab using FragmentTabs, I Used this sample and library https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip for the FragmentTabs and this one http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/969 for the ExpandableLayout.

Here is my layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayout
    android:id="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    expandable:el_headerLayout="@layout/view_header"
    expandable:el_contentLayout="@layout/view_content"
    android:background="#ffff"/>

<com.andexert.expandablelayout.library.ExpandableLayoutListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/first"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And my Activity.java

```
public class ActivityTareas extends Fragment {
private final String[] array = {"Hello", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome", "World", "Android", "is", "Awesome"};


public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static ActivityTareas newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    ActivityTareas fragment = new ActivityTareas();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tm_activity_inicio_tareas, container, false); //The Exception points at this line
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.view_row, R.id.header_text, array);
    final ExpandableLayoutListView expandableLayoutListView = (ExpandableLayoutListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    expandableLayoutListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    return view;

}
```

}

Any suggestions?

Comment: hey , did you find any solution for this , as I am getting the same error and didn't find any solution

Comment: Hey, solved my problem by using this library https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout instead of this one http://android-arsenal.com/details/1/969 hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

you should add Kotlin plugins in build.gradle() , then can use this library .

```
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version'
```

and this line :

```
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the code in your layout.xml from `xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to `xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: Also, remove `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` in `onCreateView` method.

Comment: When I change to `xmlns:expandable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto it gives me` this error:
`No resource identifier found for attribute 'el_headerLayout' in package`

Answer (score 0):

Since there doesn't seem to be any answer for this, here is the way I fixed it.

To fix the exception, declare the namespace "app" with `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and instead of using `<fooNamespace>:el_headerLayout` and `<fooNamespace>:el_contentLayout`, use respectively `app:el_headerLayout` and `app:el_contentLayout` to assign your layouts.

Cheers.

Comment: It doesn't work. Getting error "HeaderLayout and ContentLayout cannot be null!"

Comment: @IgorJanković  I edited my answer, I forgot the "el_" prefix on attributes. Can you try and give me some feedback ?